# Entity Framework Many-Many Relationship Create 3rd Table Manually

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF for a CMS type application I am working on. I have come across this issue where I need a M2M (Many-to-Many) relationship and I wish to create the 3rd table myself. (To be honest I create all tables myself, personal preference).

I have been searching Google and it seems manually creating the 3rd table is not possible and EF does it, is there anyway around this?

For example here is a test class.

```
    public class Banners
{

    public int ID{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}

    //other columns..

    public IList<Page> Pages{get;set;}

}


public class Page
{

    public int ID{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}

    //other columns..

    public IList<Banners> Bannerss{get;set;}

}
//MAKE THIS TABLE MANUALLY..?
public class BannersInPages

{

    public int BannerId{get;set;}
    public int PageId{get;set;}
    public int BannerSortOrder{get;set;}
    public string Placement {get;set;}  
}
```

From the class above, you can see a Banner can be in many pages, and a page can have many banners. With the 3rd column BannerInPages which stores the relationship plus two additional columns to specify the sorting and placement of the banner on the page.

How can I link this data using EF fluent API? Is this possible?

Kind regards

Asim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want you need to create two one to many relationships between those two entities and `BannersInPages` entity. To do that you need to change the type of your collection navigation properties to `BannersInPages`:

```
public class Banner
{    
    //other columns..
    public IList<BannersInPages> Pages{get;set;}   
}

public class Page
{   
    //other columns..    
    public IList<BannersInPages> Banners{get;set;}   
}

public class BannersInPages    
{
    public int BannerId{get;set;}
    public int PageId{get;set;}

    public int BannerSortOrder{get;set;}
    public string Placement {get;set;} 

   // add these navigation properties too if you want (recommended)
   public virtual Banner{get;set;}
   public virtual Page{get;set} 
}
```

And the Fluent Api configurations (overriding the `OnModelCreating` method on your context) would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BannersInPages>().HasKey(a => new { a.BannerId, a.PageId});

modelBuilder.Entity<BannersInPages>()
            .HasRequired(bp=>bp.Banner)
            .HasMany(b=>b.Banners)
            .HasForeignKey(bp=>bp.BannerId);

modelBuilder.Entity<BannersInPages>()
            .HasRequired(bp=>bp.Page)
            .HasMany(b=>b.Pages)
            .HasForeignKey(bp=>bp.PageId);
```